# Regex only matches it and its, but not it's

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex to match the words it, its, and it's.

I'm using `\b` to match words, but it seems like it is only matching characters. How can I get it to match anything, but whitespace?

Here is the regex so far: `\b(it|it's|its)\b`. How can I get it to match exactly the words it, it's, and its?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one will work:

```
\bit(?:'?s)?\b
```

Your pattern doesn't work with `it's` because in the alternation the item `it` *(that is tested first)* succeeds before `it's` that is not tested at all. You can write `\b(it's|it|its)\b` too.

Comment: Good point about order of success. Wouldn't that same train of thought lead to `\b(it's|its|it)\b` though, as `it` would succeed before `its`? (I suppose the order of the first two wouldn't matter)

Comment: @Trojan: you don't have the same problem with `its` and `it` because of the word boundaries.

Comment: An apostrophe is a word boundary, then?

Comment: @Trojan: a word boundary is the limit (a zero-width assertion) between a character that is a member of the class `\w` and an other character that is not a member of this class. Thus, there is a word boundary between `t` and `'`.

Comment: why did you put '?:' ?

Comment: @Harpreet Singh: so that it wasn't captured http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: I was playing around with you regEx, its working without ':?', check this link - http://regex101.com/r/fV2sC6